# Problem in Installation of VLC media player

Tags: software-center, vlc

I downloaded vlc 2.0.1 for 32 bit ubuntu from 
http://ubuntu-15.blogspot.in/2012/06/download-offline-installer-ubuntu-1204.html.

It was in ".isi" format. Whenever I double click on it then  gedit window like blank notepad is opening. Iam new to Ubuntu. So Anyone tell me how to install it.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Using Ubuntu Software Center and  not downloading from internet is solution. Ubuntu isn't Windows, try to make yourself as much as possible familiar with Ubuntu and Linux in general, while it may look hardier than windows once you understand how it works everything will become clear and logical.

Answer (score 3):

The file format which is used by Ubuntu for installation of packages(softwares) is dpkg (debian package).

So, the file you have downloaded isn't going to work as it is not supported.

So, to download vlc the easiest way is to use `Ubuntu Software Centre`.

Here is a screenshot

[image: VLC]

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 12.04 comes with vlc 2.0.8 in its repositories.

To install it, simply open the software center, search for 'vlc' and click the install button.

Of course, you can also open a terminal and enter `sudo apt-get install vlc` or use another package manager of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1:**

One way to install VLC Player is through Ubuntu Software Centre.

- Go to Software Centre
- Search for VLC Player
- Click Install button.

It will automatically get downloaded and installed.

Done!

---

**Method 2:**

- Open terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>)
- Run command

  `$ sudo apt-get install vlc`
- When prompted whether to install packages, type Y and hit enter.

It will download and install automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can also install vlc from synaptic package manager.Run the below command on terminal to install synaptic,

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

After the installation completed,open `synaptic package manager` and search for `vlc`.Once you find that,right click on that and select `Mark for installation` option and then click on `Apply button` on top.

[image]

Or

Run the below commands on terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>,

```
sudo apt-get install vlc vlc-nox
```

Answer (score 0):

Linux does not care about fie extensions, the "isi" files you pointed to in the video look like bash scripts that automate the installation of VLC
Such files can harm your OS and expose your personal data
Just download VLC from Ubuntu Software Centre or using the command

```
$ sudo apt-get install vlc
```